# JS + CSS = не работает изменение свойства

Tags: javascript, css

Почему вариант [2] изменения свойства css работает, а [1] - нет?

```
function showDetails(elem) {
  var divElem = elem.parentNode.children[1].style.display;
  if (divElem == 'block') {
    divElem = 'none'; //[1]
    elem.parentNode.children[1].style.display = 'none'; //[2]
  } else {
    divElem = 'block';
    elem.parentNode.children[1].style.display = 'block';
  }   
}
```

Заранее спасибо :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

elem.parentNode.children[1].style.display == string, соответственно:

```
var = divElem = elem.parentNode.children[1].style.display //divElem = text
```

А во втором случае вы меняете свойство объекта.

Чтобы работал первый случай - его необходимо подкорректировать:

```
var divElem = elem.parentNode.children[1]; //divElem = ссылка на объект
divElem.style.display = 'none'; //изменяемое свойство объекта
```

Может быть будет так же работать и:

```
var divElem = elem.parentNode.children[1].style;
divElem.display = 'none';
```

Хотя здесь уже сомневаюсь. Надо проверить))

Comment: второй вариант работает, да и подходит лучше) спасибо

Answer (score 2):

```
var divElem = elem.parentNode.children[1].style.display;
```

Здесь в `divElem` **копируется** значение, потому что `...style.display` - это строка. А ссылка создается только на объект. Следующий код помещает в `divElem` **ссылку**.

```
var divElem = elem.parentNode.children[1].style;
divElem.display='none'; //эквивалентно  elem.parentNode.children[1].style.display='none';
```

Comment: отдал бы "лучший ответ" Вам, но опередили) хотя спасибо за более ясное описание.